# Rename a file with PHP right before it downloads without saving it to the server?

Tags: php

I have an Adobe Illustrator file (AI) that we currently have a link to on a website which then downloads the file to your computer.

The link looks something like this...
`http://domain.com/crm/index.php?entryPoint=fileupload_download&id=22440435-e8ee-bd6f-7612-533b2cd7690f&field=fuaifile_c&type=D1_Designs`

What I need to do is rename this file as it downloads.

So I am asking if it is possible to pass this download through another PHP file right before it downloads which would allow me to change the filename on the fly that the user downloads.  I cannot change the filename on the server but when it downloads I would like to be able to add some ID numbers to the filename on the fly if this is possibble?  Any ideas how to accomplish this without having to resave the image on the server with a new name?

Comment: What does your PHP code currently look like?  How are you offering the file for download?  How are you setting the headers?  You just need to add `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$yourFileName);` to the headers in your `index.php`.

Comment: Set this header and you should be good to go: `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="newFileName.ext"');`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Im not following?  The point of this site is to help others answer programming questions, if you read through the comments you will see this isn't as simple of a question as it may seem, I have a script I do not have access tot hat is setting the header output, I then need to relay these files through another script and output them, not to mention the source of the file requires my script to cURL and login to SuagrCRM just to get the proper file that is needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ugly, and assumes these aren't "large" files that would exceed your memory_limit, but

```
$data = file_get_contents($original_url);
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="new name with id numbers');
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
echo $data;
```

You could always enhance this to do byte serving - suck 10k from original url, spit out 10k to user, etc...

Comment: This seems more inline with what I would have to do since I cannot change the header of the original download file....this would act like a relay which seems to be what I need to do I will try it out, thanks

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is the [`Content-Disposition`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) header, as specified in [RFC 2183](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183):

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.ai
```

You can set this header using the PHP [`header()`](http://php.net/header) function.

Comment: What I failed to mention is the current URL that I download the image from is inside of SugarCRM and I cannot change that files header, I almost need a new PHP script that will download the file from the URL and then re-send it to the browser, if that makes sense, like a relay

Comment: Any reason you can't add this as a modification to SugarCRM?

Comment: Mainly just time constraints Im looking for a quick way, I think @Marc B is on to something that might work, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just set the `Content-Disposition`:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
```

(Example taken from PHP docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Adding id:

```
$id = generateIdFromSomewhere();
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded'.$id.'.pdf"');
```